# Could we prevent users from miniconda to execute non signing code?

Tags: python, security, digital-signature, miniconda

In order that no harmful scripts are executed by a large amount of users, we would like to prevent them to execute python scripts that are not issued by some specific internal teams.  We are thinking to sign scripts and allow only the execution of signed scripts by users. How could this be achieved practically ? we don't find any relevant doc on Miniconda (any version) nor on Anaconda ? Does this feature exist ?